# How to query data across collections in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

It is written in the documentation below that "If you need to query data across collections, use root-level collections."
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/data-model

If anyone knows an example of querying data across root-level collections in Firestore then please share the same.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am not asking about subcollections. I am asking for an example of querying data across root-level collections in Firestore. Can you please share the same?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My question is about querying data across root-level collections and you are marking it as possible duplicate of question "Firestore query subcollections" which is related to subcollections. Hence it is clear that my question is not at all duplicate of the question you are pointing to. Based on this fact I request you to please remove the "Possible duplicate" mark from my question.

Comment: The answer is the same: there is no way to query across multiple collections.

Comment: But the documentation clearly says " If you need to query data across collections, use root-level collections."

Comment: Google's documentation about querying across collections is very poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your specific scenario. Here's how to get comments (from 'commentsCollection' collection) related to an article.

Assume article documents are set up like this:

firestore: **articlesCollection/1234**

```
{
    title: "How to FireStore",
}
```

And comments documents are set up like this:

firestore: **commentsCollection/ABCD**

```
{
    comment: "Great article!",
    articleRef: {
        "1234": true
    }
}
```

firestore: **commentsCollection/EFGH**

```
{
    comment: "Another comment on a different article",
    articleRef: {
        "5678": true
    }
}
```

Given an article document id...

```
let articleComments = db.collection("commentCollection")
    .where('articleRef.' + articleId, '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(() => {
        // ...
    });
```

If the given article id were 1234, the comment ABCD would be the result. If the given article id were 5678, the comment EFGH would be the result.

Including the article doc query it would look something like this:

```
db.collection("articlesCollection")
    .doc(articleId)
    .get()
    .then(article => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("commentsCollection")
            .where('articleRef.' + article.id, '==', true)
            .get()
            .then(results => {
                results.forEach(function (comment) {
                    console.log(comment.id, " => ", comment.data());
                });
            });
    });
```

---

Modified from firestore docs:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/arrays

Comment: What is the benefit of using the key as the article number, instead of just doing `articleRef: '5678'` and querying for `where('articleRef', '==', '5678')` ?