# Firestore data modeling for library books + wishlist data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I'm working on a library app, and am using Firestore with the following (simplified) two collections `books` and `wishes`:

```
Book
- locationIds[] # Libraries where the book is in stock

Wish
- userId # User who has wishlisted a book
- bookId # Book that was wishlisted
```

**The challenge**: I would like to be able to make a query which gets a list of all Book IDs which have been wishlisted by a user AND are currently available in a library.

I can imagine two ways to solve this:

**APPROACH 1**

Copy the `locationIds[]` array to each Wish, containing the IDs of every location having a copy of that book.

My query would then be (pseudocode):

```
collection('wishes')
.where('userId' equals myUserId)
.where('locationIds' contains myLocationId)
```

But I expect my Wishes collection to be pretty large, and I don't like the idea of having to update the `locationIds[]` of all (maybe thousands) of wishes whenever a book's location changes.

**APPROACH 2**

Add a `wishers[]` array to each Book, containing the IDs of every user who has wishlisted it.

Then the query would look something like:

```
collection('books')
.where('locationIds' contains myLocationId)
.where('wishers' contains myUserId)
```

The problem with this is that the `wishers` array for a particular book may grow pretty huge (I'd like to support thousands of wishes on each book), and then this becomes a mess.

**Help needed**

In my opinion, neither of these approaches are ideal. If I had to pick one, I will probably go with Approach 1 simply because I don't want my Book object to contain such a huge array.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to come across this sort of problem, is there a better way?

Comment: What are the **exact** queries that you want to perform?

Comment: @AlexMamo For this question specifically, I want "get all books which have been wishlisted by this user AND are currently available in this library". Surrounding that, I'm also interested in "get all books wishlisted by this user", "get all users who have wishlisted this book",  "get all books in this library", "get all libraries which have this book", to name the relevant queries. The current datastructure I have supports all these individual queries, just not the compound query I'm asking for in the question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add also your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try dividing the query in two different requests. For instance, in pseudocode:

```
wishes = db.collection('wishes').where('userId', '==', myUserId)
book_ids = [wish.bookId for wish in wishes]
books = db.collection('books').where('bookId', 'in', book_ids)
result = [book.bookId for book in books if book.locationIds]
```

Notice that this is just an example, this code probably doesn't work, since I haven't tested it and the keywork `in` just supports [10 values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations). But you get the idea. A good idea would be adding the length of the `locationIds` or whether it's empty or not in a separate attribute so you could omit the last iteration querying the books with:

```
books = db.collection('books').where('bookId', 'in', book_ids).where('hasLocations', '==', True)
```

Although you would still have to iterate to only get the `bookId`.

Also, you should avoid using arrays in Firestore since it doesn't have native support for them, as explained [in their blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Is it mandatory to use NoSQL? Maybe you could do this M:M relation better in SQL. Bear in mind that I'm no database expert though.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the `in` array check, I didn't know we could do that! But unfortunately the 10-value maximum is a problem for me, because users can have easily more than 10 books on their wishlist (likely even hundreds). Do you have any alternative suggestions? 

(And I'm stuck with NoSQL because everything else on my app is done with Firestore and I don't think I'll want to migrate to a SQL platform just for this...)

Comment: @JunShernChan Using the `in` operation another option would be using a loop to iterate over queries of 10 values, but I reckon this would be a bit overkill and not an option to look after. Since you want to stick to a NoSQL database, where you cannot query different collections/tables, you should start using [embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#embedded-document-pattern) or the [subset pattern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#subset-pattern).

Comment: @JunShernChan Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48140507/10810527) from another similar question in SO, as it explains how to query multiple collections. I'm sure whether it works or not since I haven't tested it, but it does seem feasible and may inspire you.